# Creating nuget packages for solutions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

We have a development team that is not familiar with nuget, and we have a severe need for it, specifically to create packages out of our projects.

The hierarchy of projects in our solutions is analogous to:

**Project A** depends on:
*Projects B, C, D, E*

**Project B** depends on
*Projects C, E*

**Project C** depends on
*Projects A, F*

Though I am a familiar consumer of nuget packages, I have never built my own package.

**Question:**
When a solution requires projects A, B, C from above, will nuget resolve the fact that some of the dependencies are the same for the projects?

Comment: "Project A depends on Project C", "Project C depends on Project A"; only one of these can be true

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I agree with Ivan Vargas. If there has same version of dependencies in different packages, the dependencies will be installed only once. If the dependencies has the same name but with different version, you could resolve the conflict issue with Version Range in this doc: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/dependency-versions  If any other questions, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. When constructing a nuget package, you can specify the dependencies for the package and nuget will install whatever dependencies are missing. Of course, this will depend on the version of the dependent assemblies the spec file indicates. Look into https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuspec for more details.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: I assume you have a typo in your example since you have a circular dependency on projects A and C.